# Modifying and consolidating ggplot2 line colors after building

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Given a collection of `ggplot2` line graphs, is it possible to extract the line-to-color mapping for each graph and then change the colors of all the lines across the collection so I can use a single guide in patchwork?

Example:

```
library("tibble")
library("ggplot2")
library("patchwork")
 
d1 <- 
  tribble(
    ~g,  ~x, ~y,
    "a",  1,  1,
    "a",  2,  2,
    "b",  1,  2,
    "b",  2,  1
    )

p1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y, group = g)) + geom_line( aes(color=g))

d2 <- 
  tribble(
    ~g,  ~x, ~y,
    "b",  1,  3,
    "b",  2,  5,
    "c",  1,  5,
    "c",  2,  4
    )

p2 <-ggplot(d2, aes(x = x, y = y, group = g)) + geom_line( aes(color=g))

p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

```
cols <- c("a" = "red", "b" = "blue", "c" = "green")

p1a <- p1 + scale_colour_manual(values = cols)
p2a <- p2 + scale_colour_manual(values = cols)

p1a + p2a + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

In the first plot, `pl+p2` use different color mappings so get different guides.

In the second plot, I specify a color mapping vector post-hoc and then patchwork can combine the guides.

My question is how can I extract the data pragmatically given just p1 and p2 to build the cols variable?

I see that, in the above:

```
> p1$mapping$group[[2]]
g

> p1$data$g
[1] "a" "a" "b" "b"
```

which is an approach that might work in this case, but would break if the group wasn't the color aesthetic in `geom_line`.

Comment: Can you give some example code that frames what you're going for here?

Comment: Hi @teunbrand.  Thanks for your reply, example added at your request!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no straightforward way to do this. What we can do, is write our own function that merges scales of plot inputs. In the code below, we loop through a list of plots, extract and merge their limits, and build a new scale based on the first plot. (Not tested for any other example than this, it is unlikely to work for continuous scales)

```r
merge_scales <- function(..., aesthetic = "colour") {
  plotlist <- list(...)
  
  # Extract scales
  plotlist <- lapply(plotlist, ggplot_build)
  scales   <- lapply(
    plotlist, function(x) x$plot$scales$get_scales(aesthetic)
  )
  
  # Calculate new limits
  limits <- lapply(scales, function(x) x$get_limits())
  limits <- Reduce(union, limits)
  
  # Copy scale, assign new limits
  scale <- scales[[1]]$clone()
  scale$limits <- limits
  
  # Reset caches
  scale$palette.cache  <- NULL
  scale$n.breaks.cache <- NULL
  scale
}
```

You should then be able to just slap on this function in your patchwork with the `&` operator to apply the new scale to all preceding plots.

```r
library("tibble")
library("ggplot2")
library("patchwork")

d1 <- 
  tribble(
    ~g,  ~x, ~y,
    "a",  1,  1,
    "a",  2,  2,
    "b",  1,  2,
    "b",  2,  1
  )

p1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(x = x, y = y, group = g)) + geom_line( aes(color=g))

d2 <- 
  tribble(
    ~g,  ~x, ~y,
    "b",  1,  3,
    "b",  2,  5,
    "c",  1,  5,
    "c",  2,  4
  )

p2 <-ggplot(d2, aes(x = x, y = y, group = g)) + geom_line( aes(color=g))

p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect") & merge_scales(p1, p2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### EDIT

I think it is mostly unavoidable to get the 'scale is already present' warning when we're not allowed to touch `p1` and `p2` upstream (maybe if you wrap everything in `suppressWarnings()`?). What you *can* do, it so use a template scale in the function, so that might make things a bit easier.

```r
merge_scales <- function(..., template = scale_colour_discrete()) {
  plotlist  <- list(...)
  aesthetic <- template$aesthetics[[1]]
  
  # Extract scales
  plotlist <- lapply(plotlist, ggplot_build)
  scales   <- lapply(
    plotlist, function(x) x$plot$scales$get_scales(aesthetic)
  )
  
  # Calculate new limits
  limits <- lapply(scales, function(x) x$get_limits())
  limits <- Reduce(union, limits)
  
  # Copy scale, assign new limits
  scale <- template$clone()
  scale$limits <- limits
  scale
}
```

Then use it like this:

```r
p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect") & 
  merge_scales(
    p1, p2, 
    template = scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green"))
  )
```

Comment: I interpreted your question as 'after we've build plots, how can we consolidate the value-to-colour mapping between different plots?'. If you just need the unique values that the colour aesthetic takes in your plots, you can adapt the function above to return `limits` early.

Comment: My sincere apologies, I totally failed to understand your answer.  Mea maxima culpa.  I thought it was doing something with the limits.  It wasn't until I looked at it in a lot more detail I figured it out.  (Every time I think I might have a handle on ggplot2, it throws me a curve ball like this!).  Any thoughts on how I can avoid the "Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the
existing scale." message I get when I add my own palette with scale_color_manual()?

Comment: Please see edit, where I tried to address this bit